# Can Vite be made to silently fail when unable to locate file in manifest?

Tags: laravel, vite, production

I feel like Laravel's Vite implementation has introduced a new potential point of complete failure on our production site.

In the past if an image was misnamed in the html, eg `photo.png` instead of `photo.jpg`, the page would still load just fine, but there would simply be a broken image link.

Now, with Laravel's Vite class generating image paths for code such as `<img src="{{ Vite::asset('resources/images/abc.jpg') }}">` the site will throw a `500 server error` if `abc.jpg` cannot be found. The logged error is:

```
[previous exception] [object] (Exception(code: 0): Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: resources/images/abc.jpg. at /var/www/html/laravel-prod/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Vite.php:737)
```

Of course I understand there's an issue with underlying QA processes if such a piece of code makes it into production. But nonetheless, I highly dislike how Vite has introduced this brittleness.

Is there a way to configure Vite to fail silently if it cannot locate a resource in the generated manifest?